# Python Site Scrape Help Needed

Tags: python, html, regex

I'm new to python (and a lot of coding outside of SQL, SAS, and a little R) and I am trying to use it to build a dataset based on data from a number of different web pages. Thanks in advance for your help.

I am using Python 3.4.4 and have successfully pulled the code of the sites, but I'm having trouble with writing the regex code to isolate the specific data elements/metrics I want. Below is a sample of the webpage's code and I want to isolate the whole numbers by themselves between the tdclass statements.

```
<tr class="Company"><td class="Company"> <ahref="http://www.theacsi.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=149&catid=&Itemid=214&amp;c=Liz+Claiborne&amp;i=Apparel" id="L">Liz Claiborne</a> </td><td class="Baseline"> 84 </td><td class="Y1995"> 81 </td><td class="Y1996"> 81 </td><td class="Y1997"> 77 </td><td class="Y1998"> 78 </td><td class="Y1999"> 76 </td><td class="Y2000"> 79 </td><td class="Y2001"> 79 </td><td class="Y2002"> 80 </td><td class="Y2003"> 78 </td><td class="Y2004"> 79 </td><td class="Y2005"> 78 </td><td class="Y2006"> 81 </td><td class="Y2007"> 79 </td><td class="Y2008"> 79 </td><td class="Y2009"> 82 </td><td class="Y2010"> 79 </td><td class="Y2011"> 79 </td><td clas
```

Comment: I find this page brilliant for making regex: https://txt2re.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to look at lxml and xpath not to mention other scraping soft. Thousends of posts in aera. Check the link below:

http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/scenarios/scrape/

If you dont like to use other modules use build RE (Regular expressions) module, which provides you usefull informations about how to extract specific text from string.